# Run all Python files in a directory

Tags: python, bash, matplotlib

What is the best way to run all Python files in a directory?

```
python *.py
```

only executes one file. Writing one line per file in a shell script (or make file) seems cumbersome. I need this b/c I have a series of small matplotlib scripts each creating a png file and want to create all of the images at once.

PS: I'm using the bash shell.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

bash has loops:

```
for f in *.py; do python "$f"; done
```

Comment: I should have thought of that myself ;)

Comment: is there a way to run all Python scripts in a directory of directories? For example: I have a "main" folder that has 3 subfolders and I want to run all Python scripts inside those folders

Answer (score 21):

An alternative is to use xargs. That allows you to parallelise execution, which is useful on today's multi-core processors.

```
ls *.py|xargs -n 1 -P 3 python
```

The *-n 1* makes xargs give each process only one of the arguments, while the *-P 3* will make xargs run up to three processes in parallel.