# Running a folder/directory as a whole in Python

Tags: python, powershell, directory

Can I run a Python folder or directory as a whole to execute all the `.py` files in it?
Edit: I'm using Windows Powershell.

Comment: You mean to run all `.py` scripts in specific folder? one by one?

Comment: If you can use bash, you could try something like `ls *.py | while read line ; do python $line <optionally specify some arguments> ; done`

Comment: In separate processes or all in the same process?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
import os
path = 'path\\to\\your\\directory\\'
files = os.listdir (path)
for i in files:
    if i.endswith('.py'):
        os.system("python "+path+i)
```

Answer (score 7):

For `bash`, This was already answered at [Run all Python files in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5015316/run-all-python-files-in-a-directory)

You can run:

```
for f in *.py; do python "$f"; done
```

If you're on `Powershell`, You can use:

```
Get-Childitem -Path c:\path\to\scripts -Filter *.py | % {python $_.FullName}
```

`EDIT`: Like Duncan said, This is a shorter solution on `Powershell`:

```
ls C:\path\to\scripts\*.py | %{ python $_.Fullname}
```

Comment: I did see that question, however I'm using Windows Powershell.

Comment: @always_confused, please mention that you're on Powershell/cmd in the question or add it as a tag.

Comment: If writing a script I'd write `Get-ChildItem` out in full, but if this is being done interactively it's much shorter just to do `ls *.py | % { python $_.FullName }`

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell you can use:

```
Get-Childitem -Path c:\to\folder\ -Filter *.py | % {& $_.FullName}
```