# How do I run 100 python files 2 minutes apart?

Tags: python, cron, cron-task

I want to run around 100 python scripts 2 minutes apart everyday to ensure that none of them overlap. I am using linux/Mac system.

Is there a dynamic way of doing this using cron tab? Or perhaps is there a scheduler program that might make it easier?

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way would be to develop your own python script to manage this, using the python time module to add the delay.

```
import time
time.sleep(120) # 2 minute delay.
```

To call your script just import the file then execute it by running.

```
exec('file.py') #this is for python 3
```

Answer (score 2):

Is the goal here to have the files execute *exactly* two minutes apart, or are you hoping to have one job just finish before the other executes?

If you are solely concerned with `script1` finishing before `script2`, crontab should be able to do this in cronjob with a command like this:

```
script1 && script2
```

There is a decent example of this in the comments of [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxadmin/comments/3ndn4j/crontab_how_to_setup_jobs_with_dependency_jobs/).

If you do in fact want to have the scripts execute exactly 2 minutes apart, maybe you could approach by [setting a specific execution time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5200551/how-to-set-a-cron-job-to-run-at-a-exact-time)? Of course this may be somewhat sensitive to failures / not the most robust method, so adding some sort of event listener, etc. might be a better option.

Hope this helps a little bit!

Answer (score 1):

Edit: This does not answer the OPs question but I will leave it up here in case anyone else misinterpreted the question title and came searching for the corresponding answer.

I would write a (most likely bash) script that will execute all 100 scripts and then call that one script with crontab. The cron line for every 2 minutes is as follows:

```
*/2 * * * * <file>
```

Here is a bash script that runs all python scripts in a directory, assuming all 100 scripts are in the same directory (taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5015316/2750819)).

```
for f in *.py; do python "$f"; done
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I think I may have been a little confusing in the wording of my question. Instead of running all 100 every 2 minutes, I would like to run each individual file (up tp 100) two minutes apart.

Comment: I see; in that case I would look at @Sam Gaudet's answer.